# Get requests per second from node.js http server

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-http-proxy

Is there a way in `node.js` to get the **number of open connections** and **number of requests per second** from a http server?

Assume the following simple server:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end("Hello World!");
}).listen(80);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use [ApacheBench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) or [httperf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/httperf/).

Comment: I want these numbers from the server (node.js), not client.

Comment: Ah right. Check out [node-measured](https://github.com/felixge/node-measured).

Answer (score 9):

This is what I usually do when I want to double-check numbers ab/httperf/wrk/siege report:

```
var served = 0;
var concurrent = 0;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  concurrent++;
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  setTimeout(function() { // emulate some async delay
    served++;
    concurrent--;
    res.end("Hello World!");
  }, 10);
}).listen(80);

setInterval(function() {
  console.log('Requests per second:' + served);
  console.log('Concurrent requests:' + concurrent);
  served = 0;
}, 1000);
```